# Android: call a method after a textView is changed

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, onclicklistener

a simple issue here, but one I haven't been able to find a simple solution for. My Android app has a button that calls a calculations-heavy method which may take a while to return results. I want the user to know that the app is working, not frozen, so upon hitting that button I want to display a textView with a loading message, then call the method and load its results to another textView (while also hiding the first one). How can I make sure the method is started only AFTER the loading message becomes visible, because the code below fires the method when it's still not visible?

```
        buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadingMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findSolution();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for a Progress Bar, it's a an android feature that android made for you.
Here is a link for the official google site: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

I usually would just throw a Toast message to let them know they should wait, without having to use progress bar, for example when button is clicked it will display a message saying"please wait,loading"
inside the button `Toast.makeText(this, "Loading,Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
and you then can change the lenght of how long it should appear, lenghtshort is just 2 seconds